# How to handle different linked files in FOrge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

we are taking Revit files from BIM360 to forge and we notice the following behaviour. If the host model has linked (active workshared) Revit files in it it fails to open. IF I remove the linked files, the document opens and the job finishes succesfully.

We found out the following if the linked files are linking to active workshared files it tends to fail. If I take the linked files put them in a package and publish them, (so the end up in the shared directory on BIM360 doc. management) and link those published Revit files into thew host than the job finishes correctly.
My question 
 1. Is this behaviour as intended?
 2. Is it possible to tell forge to ignore linked files and continue opening the document.

Comment: If the "job" is Forge translation job of the Model Derivative API, you will have to publish the WorkSharing Revit model, i.e. C4R model, to BIM360 Docs via Manage Cloud Model of the Revit UI under Collaboration tab, then you can open it with Forge Viewer

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, could you kindly correct me? Thanks!

Comment: No we are using the Design Automation API to retrieve data from the host file. By the way what do you mean with the Forge viewer?

Comment: Ok, do you see any error message in the workItem report? About the Forge Viewer part, I make an assumption that you're talking about the translation "job".